# How can I check if an array is null

Tags: javascript

I want to make a command, so that i attach roles in discord. when i want to attach allowed roles, it work, when i want to atach unallowed roles (like admin, team, etc) it works too and denies. but when I just type !role, it outputs nothing. That isn´t bad, sure, but after some tries, i realized that the parameters, when i don´t enter a single one, aren´t `null`. I tried it with

```
if(args == null) {
            message.channel.send(`You haven´t entered a role!`);
    }
```

args is the array, where the command parameters are saved.
I know that without one single parameter, the array doesn´t even exist, so how can I tell the bot
"If there is no array coming with the command, then..."

Comment: Ok, so what does `args` actually contain?

Comment: `if(args === null || args === undefined || args.length === 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will evaluate to true if the `args` variable is not an array or if the array does not have at least one value.

`` if (!Array.isArray(args) || args.length === 0) {
    message.channel.send(`You haven´t entered a role!`);
} ``

Comment: It might also be useful to check typeof args === 'undefined'. Otherwise you get an uncaught reference error

Comment: @D.Kendall Yeah, good catch. As long as they've at least declared the variable, it should be fine (the Array.isArray(args)) check will pick it up. But you're correct, if the args variable isn't even defined yet than it will throw.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it out and got that error, so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: `Array.isArray` was introduced in ES5.  A polyfill is available if not targeting ES5+.